# 502 bad gateway error with upstream prematurely closed connection?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run an machine learning inference server on docker container with AWS sagemaker , Flask, Nginx and Gunicorn. I have tried running with  a c5.xlarge instance and c5.4xlarge instance on AWS sagemaker and it always breaks when run on a c5.xlarge instance.

When the request comes to check health of the application by loading the ML model which is around 300 mb. When inference endpoint is called, it checks if the model is up and running in the worker and if not get the ML model up and then run the prediction with data. I usually call the model with <=5MB data .

Nginx Config:

```
worker_processes auto;
daemon off; # Prevent forking


pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  # defaults
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

  upstream gunicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080 deferred;
    client_max_body_size 5m;

    keepalive_timeout 10000;

    location ~ ^/(ping|invocations) {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
    }

    location / {
      return 404 "{}";
    }
  }
}
```

gunicorn :

```
subprocess.Popen(['gunicorn',
                             '--timeout', str(model_server_timeout),
                             '-k', 'gevent',
                             '-b', 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock',
                             '-w', str(model_server_workers),
                             '--error-logfile', '-',
                             '--access-logfile', '-',
                             '--preload',
                             'wsgi:app'])
```

I have looked at the timeout (it is already set at 60 secs for gunicorn), tried preloading the app, and the logs thrown to stdout have only upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response in the error.

Answer (score 0):

How long does your container usually respond to requests? If you use the container in a hosted Endpoint, the container has to respond to requests within 60 seconds. It might be helpful to set the gunicorn timeout to be a little lower than 60 seconds.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html

It looks like the response time depends on the instance type. If this is the case, and you do want to use c5.xlarge instance type for example, you can try to create a batch transform job instead of using a real time inference endpoint. Batch transform job does allow >60 seconds response time for each request.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateTransformJob.html

Hope this helps!

-Han